# Drawing a transformer with multiple windings with circuitikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, circuitikz, circuits

I'm trying to draw a transformer with multiple windings with circuitikz similar to the figure shown here (except I'd like to have multiple primary windings and a single secondary winding):

[image]

(Source: https://sub.allaboutcircuits.com/images/02141.png)

I have code for a single winding transformer here:

```
\begin{circuitikz}[american]
\draw (0,0) node [transformer core](T){}
      (T.A1) node[above] {A1}
      (T.A2) node[below] {A2}
      (T.B1) node[above] {B1} 
      (T.B2) node[below] {B2}
      (T.base) node{K};
\draw (T.A1) --++(-2,0);
\draw (T.A2) --++(-2,0);
\draw (T.B1) --++(2,0);
\draw (T.B2) --++(2,0);
\end{circuitikz}
```

The output is shown here:
[image]

Is there a way to adapt this to have three windings on the primary side and one winding on the secondary side?

Comment: you need to compose transformer from inductors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is one way to achieve this diagram

[image]

```
\documentclass[margin=0.5cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{circuitikz}

\begin{document}

\ctikzset{bipoles/thickness=1} 
\begin{circuitikz}[line width=0.25mm]

\draw (0,0) to[L] ++ (0,1.5) --++ (2,0) to[R, bipoles/length=1cm, l=load \#2] ++ (0,-1.5) --++ (-2,0);
\draw (0,2) to[L] ++ (0,1.5) --++ (2,0) to[R, bipoles/length=1cm, l=load \#1] ++ (0,-1.5) --++ (-2,0);
\draw (-0.8,0.75) to[L, mirror] ++ (0,2) --++ (-2,0) to[sV] ++ (0,-2) --++ (2,0);
\draw (-0.33,0.25) -- (-0.33,3.25);
\draw (-0.47,0.25) -- (-0.47,3.25);

\end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```